# How to correct/standardize variable names if their format is not consistent

Tags: r

I am writing a script that loads RData files containing the results of earlier experiments and parses data frames saved in them. I've noticed that, while the names of variables are not consistent , for instance, sometimes `symbol` is called `gene_name` or `gene_symbol`. The order of variables is also different between the different data frames, so I can't just rename them all with `colnames(df) <- c('a', 'b', ...)`

I'm looking for a way to rename variables based on their name that won't give an error if that variable isn't found. The below is what I want to do, but (ideally) without needing dozens of conditional statements.

```
if ('gene_name' %in% colnames(df)) {
    df <- df %>% dplyr::rename('symbol' = gene_name)
}
```

In the below example, I'd like to find an elegant way to rename the variable `b` to `D` that I can use safely on data frames that lack a variable `b`

```
x <- data.frame('a' = c(1,2,3), 'b' = c(4,5,6))
y <- data.frame('a' = c(1,2,3), 'c' = c(4,5,6))
dfs <- list(x,y)
dfs.fixed <- lapply(dfs, function(x) ?????)
```

Desired result:

```
dfs.fixed
[[1]]
  a D
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  a c
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, `lapply(dfs,function(x) {colnames(x) <- gsub("^b$","D",colnames(x)); x})` but I suspect you may not like how that scales with your real data. Although with lots of different cases I wouldn't use an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

**STEP 1**
A function substituting a list of colnames with another string (both info parameterized):

```
colnames_rep<-function(df,to_find,to_sub)
{
  colnames(df)[which(colnames(df) %in% to_find)]<-to_sub
  return(df)
}
```

**STEP 2**
Use `lapply` to apply the function over each `data.frame`:

```
lapply(dfs,colnames_rep,to_find=c("b"),to_sub="D")
[[1]]
  a D
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

[[2]]
  a c
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Thanks to [divibisan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8366499/divibisan) for the suggestion

Comment: That's a good idea. I always forget about writing simple functions like this in `R`. If you change the `==` to `%in%` then it can accept multiple values of `to_find` at once.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rename_at` with `map`

```
map(dfs, ~ .x %>%
               rename_at(b, sub, pattern = "^b$", replacement = "D"))
#[[1]]
#  a D
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6

#[[2]]
#  a c
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that is similar in concept to Terru_theTerror's, but extends it by allowing regular expressions. It might be overkill, but ...

First, we define a simple "map" that maps *to* the desired name (first string in each vector of the list) *from* any string (remaining strings in each vector). The function that does the matching accepts an argument of `fixed=FALSE`, in which case the 2nd and remaining strings can be regular expressions, which gives more power and responsibility.

If using `fixed=TRUE` (the default), then the map might look like this:

```
colnamemap <- list(
  c("symbol", "gene_name", "gene_symbol"),
  c("D", "c", "quux"),
  c("bbb", "b", "ccc")
)
```

where `"gene_name"` and `"gene_symbol"` will both be changed to `"symbol"`, etc. If you want to use patterns (`fixed=FALSE`), however, you should be *as specific as possible* to preclude mis- or multiple-matches (across columns).

```
colnamemapptn <- list(
  c("symbol", "^gene_(name|symbol)$"),
  c("D", "^D$", "^c$", "^quux$"),
  c("bbb", "^b$", "^ccc$")
)
```

The function that does the actual remapping:

```
fixfunc <- function(df, namemap, fixed = TRUE, ignore.case = FALSE) {
  compare <- if (fixed) `%in%` else grepl
  downcase <- if (ignore.case) tolower else c
  newcn <- cn <- colnames(df)
  newnames <- sapply(namemap, `[`, 1L)
  matches <- sapply(namemap, function(nmap) {
    apply(outer(downcase(nmap[-1]), downcase(cn), Vectorize(compare)), 2, any)
  }) # dims: 1=cn; 2=map-to
  for (j in seq_len(ncol(matches))) {
    if (sum(matches[,j]) > 1) {
      warning("rule ", sQuote(newnames[j]), " matches multiple columns: ",
              paste(sQuote(cn[ matches[,j] ]), collapse=","))
      matches[,j] <- FALSE
    }
  }
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(matches))) {
    rowmatches <- sum(matches[i,])
    if (rowmatches == 1) {
      newcn[i] <- newnames[ matches[i,] ]
    } else if (rowmatches > 1) {
      warning("column ", sQuote(cn[i]), " matches multiple rules: ",
              paste(sQuote(newnames[ matches[i,]]), collapse=","))
      matches[i,] <- FALSE
    }      
  }
  if (any(matches)) colnames(df) <- newcn
  df
}
```

(You might extend it to ensure unique-ness, using `make.names` and/or `make.unique`. There's also `ignore.case`, not really tested here but easily done, I believe.)

I'm going to extend your sample data by including one that will match multiple patterns resulting in ambiguity:

```
x <- data.frame('a' = c(1,2,3), 'b' = c(4,5,6))
y <- data.frame('a' = c(1,2,3), 'c' = c(4,5,6))
z <- data.frame('cc' = 1:3, 'ccc' = 2:4)
dfs <- list(x,y,z)
```

where the third `data.frame` has two columns that match my third non-pattern vector. When there are multiple matches, I think the safer thing to do is warn about it and change none of them.

This is correct, fixed-strings only:

```
lapply(dfs, fixfunc, colnamemap, fixed=TRUE)
# [[1]]
#   a bbb
# 1 1   4
# 2 2   5
# 3 3   6
# [[2]]
#   a D
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6
# [[3]]
#   cc bbb
# 1  1   2
# 2  2   3
# 3  3   4
```

This incorrectly uses the strings as patterns, which causes one of them to warn about multiple matches:

```
lapply(dfs, fixfunc, colnamemap, fixed=FALSE)
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   rule 'D' matches multiple columns: 'cc','ccc'
# [[1]]
#   a bbb
# 1 1   4
# 2 2   5
# 3 3   6
# [[2]]
#   a D
# 1 1 4
# 2 2 5
# 3 3 6
# [[3]]
#   cc bbb
# 1  1   2
# 2  2   3
# 3  3   4
```

A better use of `fixed=FALSE`, with strict patterns instead:

```
lapply(dfs, fixfunc, colnamemapptn, fixed=FALSE)
# same output as the first call
```